# How to get the difference URI between 2 collection in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have two collections .

I need to get difference uri between the two collections based on the file name.

Example Scenario :

```
Collection 1:

/data/1.xml
/data/2.xml
/data/3.xml


collection 2:

/test/1.xml
/test/2.xml
/test/3.xml
/test/4.xml
/test/5.xml

output:
/data/1.xml
/data/2.xml
/data/3.xml
/test/4.xml
/test/5.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two alternative solutions:

First approach, put each of the items in the map, using a consistent key(substring after the last slash), and then select the first item in the map for each key:

```
let $x := (
  "/data/1.xml",
  "/data/2.xml",
  "/data/3.xml")
let $y := (
  "/test/1.xml",
  "/test/2.xml",
  "/test/3.xml",
  "/test/4.xml",
  "/test/5.xml")
let $intersection := map:map()
let $_ := ($x, $y) ! ( 
  let $key := tokenize(., "/")[last()] 
  return 
    map:put($intersection, $key, (map:get($intersection, $key), .))
)
return 
  for $key in map:keys($intersection)
  for $uri in map:get($intersection, $key)[1]
  order by number(replace($uri, ".*/(\d+).xml", '$1'))
  return $uri
```

Second approach, ensure that only the first item is set for a given key:

```
let $x := (
  "/data/1.xml",
  "/data/2.xml",
  "/data/3.xml")
let $y := (
  "/test/1.xml",
  "/test/2.xml",
  "/test/3.xml",
  "/test/4.xml",
  "/test/5.xml")

let $intersection := map:map()
let $_ := ($x, $y) ! ( 
  let $key := tokenize(., "/")[last()] 
  return 
    if (fn:exists(map:get($intersection, $key))) then ()
    else map:put($intersection, $key, .)
)
return 
  for $uri in map:get($intersection, map:keys($intersection))
  order by number(replace($uri, ".*/(\d+).xml", '$1'))
  return $uri
```

The `order by` is optional, but with maps you may not have consistent ordering of the keys. Customize for what you need (i.e. /data/ uris first, and then /test/ uris, etc), or remove if you don't care about the order of the URIs.

Comment: Thanks lot..Its very useful to me.

Answer (score 4):

Using set delta as David suggests is correct, but you will need to first generate filename keys for the URIs. Maps are very helpful for this, which make it easy to keep a filename key associated with its original URI.

First generate two maps with filename keys and URI values. Then, using set delta on the map keys, generate a sequence of diff filenames. Then get the URIs for those filenames from its source map:

```
let $x := (
  "/data/1.xml",
  "/data/2.xml",
  "/data/3.xml")
let $y := (
  "/test/1.xml",
  "/test/2.xml",
  "/test/3.xml",
  "/test/4.xml",
  "/test/5.xml")
let $map-x := map:new($x ! map:entry(tokenize(., '/')[last()], .))
let $map-y := map:new($y ! map:entry(tokenize(., '/')[last()], .))
let $keys-diff-y := map:keys($map-y)[not(. = map:keys($map-x))]
let $diff-y := map:get($map-y, $keys-diff-y)
return ($x, $diff-y)
```

Comment: If using map:map anyhow, you could probably use map operators instead: https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/im-a-map#map-operators

Comment: @grtjn The map operators are fussy about the keys and values being the same so it’s not possible to simply use the subtract operator to perform the diff here since key is filename and value is URI.

Answer (score 1):

Set notation:

Delta: (Yields 'a')

```
let $c1 := ('a', 'b', 'c')
let $c2 := ('b', 'c', 'd')

return $c1[fn:not(.= $c2)]
```

Intersection: (Yields b,c)

```
let $c1 := ('a', 'b', 'c')
let $c2 := ('b', 'c', 'd')

return $c1[.= $c2]
```

Reverse c1 and c2 for the other two permutations.

For a good read, check out this [post](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2014/01/xquery-finding-values-in-one-sequence-that-arent-in-another/) from Dave Cassel